# A set of Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been reading through some exercises and solutions and came across a student's argument that seemed rather odd, though it was crucial for the proof and his answer got a full mark.

It was claimed that if $f \in {L_\infty }\left[ {0,1} \right]$ then the following set is of Lebesgue measure zero:
$$E = \left\{ {x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]|f\left( x \right) \ge {{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }} \right\}$$

I just figured that if $f\left( x \right) \equiv 1$ then $E = \left[ {0,1} \right]$ and then $m\left( E \right) = 1$.

So I'm quite baffled

Comment: It probably should be $f( x ) >\| f\|_\infty $, with strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Then in that case the set E would just be the empty set, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider for instance $f(x) = 1_{\{0\}}(x)$.

Comment: @saz  Could you please give an example of an x that is in E?

Comment: The infinity norm is not the supremum. It is the essential supremum. They are different things and it is the difference that allows $f$ to be greater (but not on a set of positive measure!).

Comment: Ah wow, got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You correctly demonstrated with a counterexample that
$$
 \left\{ {x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]|f\left( x \right) \ge {{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }} \right\}
$$ 
does not necessarily have measure zero. Correct would be that
$$
E = \left\{ {x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]|f\left( x \right) \color{red}{>} {{\left\| f \right\|}_\infty }} \right\}
$$ 
has measure zero, because $E$ is the countable union of the sets
$$
 E_n = \{ x \in [0, 1] \mid f(x) >  \| f\|_\infty + \frac 1n \}
$$
and each $E_n$ has measure zero according to the definition of 
$\| f\|_\infty $ as the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) of $|f|$, see also [L-infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity):
$$
\|f\|_{\infty }\equiv \inf\{C\geq 0:|f(x)|\leq C{\text{ for almost every }}x\}
$$